# Tag proposal: [ancient-greece]

Tags: discussion, tags

Periodically we get questions related to the music of ancient Greece, which had a unique musical culture in both practice and theory. The study of music in ancient Greece is an academic specialty and specific area of expertise.

Ancient Greek music deserves its own tag.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please edit; this is a starting point.

---

**Tag:** [ancient-greece](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancient-greece)

**Short description:** Use this tag for questions relative to the musical culture of ancient Greece, include its instruments, performance practice, notation, music theory, modes, terminology, and other relevant topics.

**Long description:**

"The roots of the Greek sciences of harmonics and acoustics go back to the fifth century B.C.[E.], perhaps even the sixth" (Andrew Barker, *Greek Musical Writings: II, Harmonic and Acoustic Theory* [Cambridge University Press, 1989], 1) and continue until at least the first century C.E. with Aristides Quintilianus (Barker, 392).

The Greeks developed a highly sophisticated theory of musical tunings and modes that is distinct from modern conceptions. ...

[From here, please feel free to fill in details. Probably should include some brief descriptions of the Greater Perfect System, the Tonoi, etc., as well as mention of some of the instruments such as aulos and hydraulus.]

Comment: To whoever the downvoter is, please leave a note to say why - this is meta, so discussion is allowed

Comment: Not the downvoter. What about ancient music in general? Should we divide it up or have all ancient music under one tag unless/until there are many questions about ancient music?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Are you proposing a single "ancient" tag that would include Greece or in addition to a dedicated tag for Greece?

Comment: I'm proposing a single ancient tag for now unless or until we get so many ancient music questions it helps to divide it up

Comment: @ToddWilcox We have at least 30 "ancient greece" questions, and it is a well-defined area of academic research, so I would still make the case for a dedicated tag. I don't know of another area where we have a batch of "ancient" questions, but it bears looking into if someone has the time and interest. You're of a mind that "history" is insufficient for those?

Comment: I feel like history is about how one thing led to another while Ancient Greek music and other ancient music has entirely separate theory and practice similar to how Carnatic has its own theory and practice, etc. History is a separate concept IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea, but I can think of few issues that may (or may not) need to be resolved.

### 1. Scope

##### Breadth

As preposed, it's a very broad topic if you want it to include:
theory, terminology, notation, instruments, performance, and more.

Perhaps it would be better to keep theory and practice separate?

But being a broad tag isn't necessarily a problem; maybe it's fine.

##### Overlap

Presumably all posts with this tag should also have the tag [history](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history).

### 2. Phrasing

The phrase "Ancient Greece" sounds like an historical place, rather than a culture – a culture that was much larger than the region ever thought of as Greece (Ellás/Ἑλλάς).

Changing it to "Ancient Greek" wouldn't work though, because that sounds like a language.

I like the phrasing "Ancient Greek music" better, but maybe that'd be too long.

Comment: I feel like a tag that has the word “music” in it is a little redundant. I feel like “Ancient Greece” on this site clearly implies “music theory and practice of Ancient Greece”.

Comment: Although it seems broad on the surface, experts in ancient Greek music tend to be experts across its various aspects. And we do have additional tags to clarify, such as "theory" and "performance-practice". I agree that "ancient-greece" is clumsy, but I agree with @ToddWilcox that in the context of this site, it's clear, much in the way "indian-classical" here clearly does not refer to architecture or handicrafts.

Comment: I said "may (or may not) need to be resolved", I'm leaning to "may not".